# How to unlock icloud account? at the same time Apple ID had been lock. Both is same ID

Tags: icloud, iphone

How to reset iCloud account? Apple ID and iCloud are the same ID. At the same time both had been block. I go to iforgot.apple.com to reset, reset link had send to iCloud.com, but then iCloud I can't get to reset password.

Comment: I have also same problem . Crazy stupid situation.

Comment: Anybody help . !

Comment: I got the same problem with my iPhone 6S Try to check if your iPhone is even possible to unlock and if yes then how. It helped me to get my iPhone unlocked. Go to Google and search for
"iCloudResult Pro Check"﻿ From there a got the information how to get it unlocked.

Comment: I've linked this to the answer about bypassing Activation Lock. Since that's not feasable for most people, you'll want to contact Apple Support to regain control of your iCloud account. THe steps there depend on how you set up iCloud and whether you have TFA/TSA/emergency fallback like SMS or emails, etc... Apple's support is online and free for account unlocks so it's best to work with them for customer support on iCloud lockouts.